# How I can make wood stop sliding once I plane it?

Tags: wood

I bought a hand plane in order to smooth and level my cuts I do using my hand saw. Before I use it in my project I tested it in a scrap piece of wood.

But once I started planing the wood, the wood itself was sliding on the table I used as my work bench.

Therefore, how I can make my wood to stop moving once I plane it?

Comment: You can use a piece of carpet padding under your work piece or one of those non slip pads you put under a floor mat or area rug to stop them from slipping.

Comment: Congrats on getting into hand tools! Stop by [woodworking.se] for loads of tips & tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 of any random [wood clamp](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BESSEY-TG-Series-24-in-Bar-Clamp-with-Wood-Handle-and-4-in-Throat-Depth-TG4-024/204986221?MERCH=REC-_-plpbrowse_multi-_-NA-_-204986221-_-N), to clamp the piece to the bench.

As you move down the piece, you'll need to relocate the clamps.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about smoothing cross cuts on a board, you are going to want to use a **Shooting Board**.

[image: Shooting Board]

If you are planing the board along the long edge, or on the surface, you will need a solid workbench with a stop at one end.  Nothing fancy, keep it simple.  The height is adjustable so the plane doesn't hit the stop.

[image: bench stop]

Comment: Fascinating, didn't know such devices existed. What I see being sold where I live is a wood worker's vise.

Comment: You will want to build your own shooting board and bench stop. That’s part of the fun.

Comment: Evidently there are other applications for shooting bards. I seen them used for truing edges of veneer before gluing to a backer. They were in essence 2 straight pieces that held the veneer straight and flat so the veneer could be planed without damage. I never seen an actual description, just illustrations. Your bench end stop is a great device, I was picturing bench dogs myself, but the end stop is even better IMO. Make sure the plywood used, is thick enough so no spring is felt while planing, the LEAST little give will mess with you bad...

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be doing woodworking on a regular basis then you may find a good woodworkers bench a valuable and important "tool" to have.

[image]

(*Photo from [Finewoodworking.com](https://www.finewoodworking.com/readerproject/2013/01/01/essential-workbench-2)*)

A solid heavy workbench provides  a stable surface to work on and the ability to hold down or onto the piece you are working on.

There are different styles of bench's but most have Two common features that are for holding wood, A vise, or three, and bench dog holes for bench dogs and hooks.

These offer different methods of holding a work piece depending on its size or how you need to interact with it.

Until you can build or buy a good workbench you can come up with alternatives  like some of the other answers here.   A planing stop on any old work surface would work well, you can buy one like [this one](https://www.highlandwoodworking.com/benchcrafted-planing-stop.aspx) or just come up with your own idea.

You could also use [bench cookies](https://www.rockler.com/bench-cookie-plus-master-kit?country=US&sid=V91041&promo=shopping&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_campaign=PL&tid=pla&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=(ROI)_Shopping_-_Top_Sellers&msclkid=4f1d662a912616f4cb323907040b063a), they look like a hockey puck but have a nonslip coating that grips the bench and the work piece or accepts accessories for bench holes or clips.
I am a customer of Rockler and like there products but there are many good woodworking tool suppliers out there.

Also, you  may find that the [Woodworking stack exchange](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) has deeper knowledge base for woodworking specific questions.

Here is good [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBS5-AV81lg) on sizing a workbench that you may find interesting.